# Writing response body with BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, basehttprequesthandler

I'm playing a little with Python 3.2.2 and want to write a simple web server to access some data remotely. This data will be generated by Python so I don't want to use the SimpleHTTPRequestHandler as it's a file server, but a handler of my own.

I copied some example from the internet but I'm stuck because **the response outputstream refuses to write the body content**.

This is my code:

```
import http.server
import socketserver

PORT = 8000

class MyHandler(http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_HEAD(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        print(self.wfile)
        self.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head>")
        self.wfile.write("<body><p>This is a test.</p>")
        # If someone went to "http://something.somewhere.net/foo/bar/",
        # then s.path equals "/foo/bar/".
        self.wfile.write("<p>You accessed path: %s</p>" % self.path)
        self.wfile.write("</body></html>")
        self.wfile.close()

try:
    server = http.server.HTTPServer(('localhost', PORT), MyHandler)
    print('Started http server')
    server.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('^C received, shutting down server')
    server.socket.close()
```

What should be a correct code for writing the response body?

Thanks a lot.

**Edit:**

The error is:

```
...
  File "server.py", line 16, in do_GET
    self.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head>")
  File "C:\Python32\lib\socket.py", line 297, in write
    return self._sock.send(b)
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: I admit I don't have the basics in Python :) so I'm a little lost trying to figure out how to work with the types and tools for transforming them...

Comment: where is this line in your code? self.wfile.write(prueba)

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. That's the trace from another test (prueba = test). I'll fix it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Python3 string is a different type than that in Python 2.x. Cast it into bytes using either

```
self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head>/html>","utf-8"))
```

or

```
self.wfile.write("<html><head><title>Title goes here.</title></head></html>".encode("utf-8"))
```

Comment: Great. Now I think if there is a way to wrap an outputstream within a "printwriter" (yes, I'm a Java programmer), hehehe. Let's look for something (or simply define a simple conversion function)

Comment: I tried with the .encode() string transformation for Python 3 but there is still an error. You have to remove the last line:
self.wfile.close()
because the do_GET will close and flush the stream by itself.

Answer (score 6):

For Python 3, prefix the string literals with a `b`:

```
self.wfile.write(b"<foo>bar</foo>")
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution here, nice! Can you confirm that this defaults to enoding utf-8?

Answer (score 4):

based on your code #comments you're probably looking for self.headers.getheaders('referer'), ie:

```
if 'http://www.icamefromthissite.com/' in self.headers.getheaders('referer'):
    do something
```

Comment: Well, not really. I only wanted to control programmatically the output of the response. The approved answer is what I needed. To encode the strings into bytes in order to send the bytes to the response. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

Just use this when using Python 3.X

```
self.wfile.write(bytes("<body><p>This is a test.</p>", "utf-8"))
```