# Python HTTPServer - get HTTP body

Tags: python, httpserver

I wrote a HTTP server using python, but I do not know how to get the HTTP body.  what should I do to get the HTTP body?

here is my code:

```
from http.server import HTTPServer,BaseHTTPRequestHandler

class MyHTTPHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print("connect from ",self.client_address)
        print(self.headers)
        length = self.headers['Content-Length']
        print(length)

addr = ('',21567)
server = HTTPServer(addr,MyHTTPHandler)
server.serve_forever()
```

Comment: Hmm. You might want to try Flask...

Comment: In any case. I feel like you should be writing HTML to some Response object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing response body with BaseHTTPRequestHandler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646657/writing-response-body-with-basehttprequesthandler)

Comment: There is no HTTP body in a `GET` request...!?

Comment: Ok I'm wrong，this is very embarrassing

Comment: @deceze You can but... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body

Comment: @LiGhTx117 Well, yes, *technically* you can send any garbage you want...

Comment: Server should close the connection if garbage comes. If HTTP/1.1 and keep-alive, then only next method request can be posted, and only POST method can contain data after the header. Tolerating garbage can lead to DoS attacks.

Answer (score 2):

Having a request body in a GET request is not a good practice, as its discussed here: [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)

Instead, you can **change your method to POST** and check there the `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html

Especially this part:

> rfile
>
> Contains an input stream, positioned at the start of the optional input data.

Comment: I've tried so many times, self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length'])) returns nothing

Comment: What do you use to test you program (curl, web brower, etc.) ?

Comment: I've solved it, I changed the method to POST, and it finally worked!

Comment: @Enrico'sRicardo could you please accept this answer as solution?